# Flutter: Videos not being played with proper aspect ratio

Tags: flutter, video

I am trying to play videos obtained from the web with its original aspect ratio. With the code I have the videos are returned with a stretched aspect ratio. I am not sure why this is. I have been doing research but cannot find a solution. How do I fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoTile1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoTile1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoTileState createState() => _VideoTileState();
}

class _VideoTileState extends State<VideoTile1> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoController;
  late Future _intitializeVideoPlayer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/nifty-gateway/video/upload/v1610827323/A/Billelis/%CE%A0%CE%91%CE%98%CE%9F%CE%A3_qyarem.mp4');
    _intitializeVideoPlayer = _videoController.initialize();
    _videoController.setLooping(true);
    _videoController.play();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _intitializeVideoPlayer,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return VideoPlayer(_videoController);
          } else {
            return Container(color: Colors.grey[800]);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AspectRatio Widget with aspectRatio: _videoController.value.aspectRatio,
VideoPlayer widget wrapper

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html

Comment: where should I add this within the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to flutter, here is my way to use and play/pause video , i hope can help you.

```
return _videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
    ? Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying
                  ? _videoPlayerController.pause()
                  : _videoPlayerController.play();
            });
          },
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                VideoPlayer(
                  _videoPlayerController,
                ),
                _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying
                    ? Container()
                    : Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.play_arrow,
                          size: 80,
                          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                        ),
                      )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    : const CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: Where should I implement the code you have recommended?

Comment: You can replace FutureBuilder with my code snippet. If you show multiple videos from the Api, you can return Listview.builder and the builder value is this code.